# Online High Scores Solution

Tags: php, iphone

Can anybody advise solution for implementing online high scores table for iPhone game ?
I mean simple engine to publish player result by http query and view global high scores table.
I'm weak in PHP so trying to find existing solution first.
Thanks.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it doesn't sound like you're trying to get someone to do your work for you, for free. This almost sou nds like a homework question.

Comment: This site is for programmers, not users. You seem to be looking for http://www.rentacoder.com/ .

Comment: Sorry. In other words - I'm looking for open-source PHP engine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial which has a downloadable "high Score" PHP script. 
http://www.flashkit.com/tutorials/Games/High-sco-Glen_Rho-657/index.php

You should know that there's a large number of people who will attempt to Game your high score table. i.e. They will try and cheat it by monitoring how you do the post, and doing the same with a new high score.

Make sure that the high score is posted with a hash key (This needs to be salted, and it needs to hash the user name and the score posted). The hash key can then be used to check the posted value was posted from your game.

BTW - There are "High Score Hosting" providers out there. That's craziness as it should be relatively simple to provide your own.

Comment: > BTW - There are "High Score Hosting" providers out there. That's craziness as it should be relatively simple to provide your own.

Thanks for link and infromation. 
I found several provider today - I'll try some of them.
Sorry for boring question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Cocoas 2D framework, I think they support some sort of global high score mechanism.